# Student on F1 visa. May I accept reimbursement for interview travel expenses?

Tags: usa, student-visa, employment

I recently bought the air plane ticket to attend an interview. The company says they will give me a check for it.

I am in F1 visa status. Can I accept this money from the company, as I remember that I am not authorized to accept money for any work until I am authorized for employment?

Is this a normal thing? Accepting a check for reimbursement for travel expenses while on f1 visa?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

You're not accepting payment for work, you're accepting reimbursement for your expenses. You are allowed to look for a job while on F1 visa, you're not allowed to actually work.

Comment: I feel that this answer is correct, but may be ambiguous to people whose second language is English.  The answer is "**YES**  You are allowed accept reimbursement for interview expenses."

Comment: *whose second language is English* means completely different from *who are not native speakers of English* although it can be assumed to mean the same thing in that sentence but the stress changes totally